# how to display photo from a relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this relationships

User.php

```
 // a user has only one user detail 
    public function userdetail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
    }
```

UserDetail.php

```
 public function user(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
```

in my controller

```
    $userprofile = User::find(Auth::id())->with('detail')->first(); 
   return view('admin.index', compact('users', 'administrators', 'messages','userprofile'));
```

but when I display it in the header.

```
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle pr-0" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="{!! url('/uploads/thumbs' , $userprofile->file_name) !!}" alt="user_auth" class="user-auth-img img-circle"/><span class="user-online-status"></span></a>
```

I can't see my photo. Can you also give me some snippet of code that if there's no uploaded picture. I display a default profile picture

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved filename in `file_name` column of `userdetails` table then,

```
$user = User::with('userdetail')->find(Auth::id());
```

In the view:

```
@if(isset($user->userdetail()->file_name))
    <img src="{{asset("uploads/thumbs/{$user->userdetail()->file_name}")}}">
@else
    <img src="{{asset("uploads/thumbs/default.jpg")}}">
@endif
```

Comment: It displays the default avatar when my user_details table has the foreign key user_id of that logged in user

Comment: I would like to share you some pictures of my db

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e242810d3449a2e5a4d4ca3efb43703b - Users table

https://gyazo.com/ba0d6ee0fc28ded5a951ab8df0cc8fcb - User_Details table

Comment: @A.Sand also print `$user` and show the returned data.

Comment: Why does it does not display my log in details? but from admin@admin.com's details?

Comment: I see relation `NULL` in the returned data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134886/discussion-between-a-sand-and-sanzeeb-aryal).